# Benefits of updating apps

Tags: ios-appstore, app-store-connect

If you update your app, does it get bumped to the top of the free apps section? Does it help improve visibility?

Answer (score 1):

Only **new** downloads will count, redownloading or downloading an update does not. And the top is based on number of downloads per time-unit.

Updating your app, on the other hand will (probably) keep users satisfied with new features and layout. If they spread the word, or advertise in any way about your application you will get more downloads. But that's not what you initiately asked.

Answer (score 0):

Top apps are based on download count and positive review based. While updating your previous app you cant make it in top rated. Updating an app will fix previous issues or adding additional features.

Answer (score 0):

Early on in the App store, updating your app would cause it to show up in the 'New' section. This is why every Friday there would be a slew of app updates as developers tried to keep their apps more visible.

Apple has since changed the store behavior so that this doesn't happen anymore.